# GROUP BY issue when using if clause and label in mysql

Tags: mysql, label

I have the following query:

```
    SELECT  if(branch='snj' or branch='nnj', 'nj', branch) as 'Branch',
            WEEK(srv_date,1) as 'Week No.',
            srv_date as 'Srv Date',
            (SUM(revenue_var)+sum(revenue)) as 'Proj Rev',
            sum(revenue) as 'Actual Rev',
            sum(revenue_var) as 'Var Rev',
            (SUM(stops)+sum(stops_var)) as 'Proj Stops',
            sum(stops) as 'Actual Stops',        
            sum(stops_var) as 'Var Stops'
    FROM `route_history`
    GROUP BY srv_date, Branch
    ORDER BY srv_date, Branch
```

The results are as expected, except when Branch is 'nj'. When it is 'nj' the two records are then shown in two rows with their own respective results as opposed to being summed and shown in one row.

Appreciate any assistance with this!

Comment: You have to put the same `if` in the grouping. You can’t reference the computed results in order/group by

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Sami Kuhmonen, the solution is below:

```
SELECT  if(branch='snj' or branch='nnj', 'nj', branch) as 'Branch',
            WEEK(srv_date,1) as 'Week No.',
            srv_date as 'Srv Date',
            (SUM(revenue_var)+sum(revenue)) as 'Proj Rev',
            sum(revenue) as 'Actual Rev',
            sum(revenue_var) as 'Var Rev',
            (SUM(stops)+sum(stops_var)) as 'Proj Stops',
            sum(stops) as 'Actual Stops',        
            sum(stops_var) as 'Var Stops'
    FROM `route_history`
    GROUP BY srv_date, if(branch='snj' or branch='nnj', 'nj', branch)
    ORDER BY srv_date, Branch
```